# Understanding a code snippet in elm (type Update)

Tags: elm

What's the following code mean?

```
type Update
    = First Field.Content
    | Last Field.Content
    | Email Field.Content
    | Remail Field.Content
    | Submit
```

(code taken from http://elm-lang.org/edit/examples/Intermediate/Form.elm line 36)

declare a new type `Update`? what does those vertical bars mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this declares a new type `Update`. The vertical bars can be read as "or". That is, something of type `Update` can be either:

1. a `First`, which has some data in it of type `Field.Content`
2. a `Last`, which has some data in it of type `Field.Content`
3. an `Email`, which has some data in it of type `Field.Content`
4. a `Remail`, which has some data in it of type `Field.Content`
5. **or** a `Submit`, which has no corresponding data.

To handle a value of type `Update`, you can use the `case`-`of` syntax to distinguish the different possible values:

```
update : Update -> State -> State
update upd st = case upd of
  First  content -> st -- do something in the situation that the Update is a First
  Last   content -> st -- do something in the situation that the Update is a Last
  Email  content -> st -- do something in the situation that the Update is a Email
  Remail content -> st -- do something in the situation that the Update is a Remail
  Submit -> st -- do something in the situation that the Update is a Submit
```

I would add a link to the documentation on the Elm website, but it's in the middle of a rewrite for the new 0.14 release. I may come back and edit it in later ;)

Comment: So, it's like an enumerate type in procedural language, right? Those `First`, `Last` more like an label, right? Is it this [link](http://elm-lang.org/learn/Syntax.elm#union-types)? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: That's the right link. Current name for this is "Union type" and Elm docs have a good overwiev, try google it over elm-lang.org. Sorry I'm not giving a link, the site structure is about to change.